# Flutter Deprecated imperative apply of Flutter's Gradle plugins issue

Tags: flutter

After I did the Deprecated imperative apply of Flutter's Gradle plugins to the flutter project. Now when I try to build Android app the following error happens.

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Note: C:\Users\Sameera\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\cloud_firestore-4.14.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
e: C:/Users/Sameera/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0c54175aa09a717c13fff1b9e499022b/transformed/jetified-play-services-measurement-api-21.5.0-api.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.gmscore.integ.client.measurement_api_measurement_api.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 44s

┌─ Flutter Fix ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                       │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then   │
│ update C:\Users\Sameera\AndroidStudioProjects\skypos_backoffice_mobile\android\build.gradle: │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'                                                      │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

My problem now is as per the guidelines (https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply) I have removed the buildscript {} part of android/build.gredle file. So I cannot change the ext.kotlin_version as suggested. What can I do now?

Answer (score 0):

> If you’ve the buildscript {} part from your android/build.gradle file, you won’t be able to change ext.kotlin_version directly.

> In this case, consider the following alternative:

1. Delete the android/settings.gradle file.
2. Run flutter create to create a new settings.gradle.
3. Update "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" to the latest version of Kotlin in
   the newly generated settings.gradle.
4. Remember to rebuild your project after making these changes.